# How to select by two unique field values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a exam results table which contains examid, level and the point got by the user. As you can see in the table

```
id     examid   level   points
228    2        1       90     
229    3        1       85     
230    3        1       65  *   
227    1        1       60  *
231    2        2       20 
232    1        1       80
```

For each unique exam the highest points will be selected.
I want to select the rows with highest points for each unique exam and unique level. The row `232` has greater point than the row `227` and `232` will be in my resultset. Another one is the row `229` which has greater point than `230`.

After selecting my resultset should be like the following:

```
id     examid   level   points
228    2        1       90     
229    3        1       85     
231    2        2       20 
232    1        1       80
```

I tried to query like

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE userid = 20 GROUP BY examid ORDER BY points
```

which results only

```
id     examid   level   points
227    1        1       60  
229    3        1       85  
228    2        1       90
```

Comment: Please be more specific: what exactly is it about those 2 rows that means they should be eliminated and the others should stay? Are you wanting to ONLY KEEP the ONE HIGHEST point score for each examid/level combination, for example?

Comment: "I want to select the rows" is not a question. What have you tried?

Comment: @Shai `"which have lower points value..."` and `"I want to select the rows with highest points for each unique exam and unique level."`. Seems pretty clear and specific. Thing lacking in this question is: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT examid, level, MAX(`points`)
FROM score
GROUP BY examid, level
ORDER BY id
```

See [SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/459c7/6/0)

Answer (score 2):

If you want all fields (including `id`), you can JOIN the table back in.

```
SELECT results.*
FROM results
JOIN (
  SELECT examid, level, max(points) AS points
  FROM results
  GROUP BY examid, level ) maxPoints
ON results.examid = maxPoints.examid
  AND results.level = maxPoints.level
  AND results.points = maxPoints.points
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the id, you can use a simple `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT examid, level, MAX(points) AS points
FROM tablename
GROUP BY examid, level
```

Comment: ... which is why my first words are "If you don't need the id", which might be quite acceptable, given the table structure.

Comment: That's great! But I will go with @PinnyM's answer which contains all fields at a time.